# python: How do I determine that a string in a huge list of strings is a duplicate if the difference between the strings is less than 5 characters?

Tags: python

If strings in a string list are compared to each other and the difference in characters is less than 5 characters, it should be considered a duplicate.

I know it is possible to do it the following way, but I think this is not feasible because the list has about 600,000 or so data and if I get all the combinations in that list, the amount of data would be 179,999,700,000.

How do I break this up? or other methods to improve performance?

```py
def check_similar(s1, s2):
    return sum(1 for a, b in zip(s1, s2) if a != b)

hash = df.hash.unique() # 600,000 data

matches = [
    s
    for s in combinations(hash, 2) # 179,999,700,000 data
    if check_similar(*s) <= 5
]
```

Comment: using bfs you can match the characters and if some not matched then count the difference and if difference exced thresold then stop traversing that branch(way) and search in other branches, if in all branches it exceed threesold then it is not similiar else you can consider them similiar

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input. Is it possible for you to show us a sample code?

Comment: You use `zip`, meaning you truncate the longer string, or it's impossible because all strings have the same length. BTW, `hash` is preserved for a built-in function, so avoid redefining it.

Comment: The reason for defining a hash was to make it easier to see the comment out. Also, all strings are the same number of characters.